# GPS works better with google maps than my App android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, maps, locationmanager

I have an app in android using GoogleMaps API.

When i use google maps, I active gps and it find me so fast.

When i use my app, it takes some seconds, and if I'm in my house, gps dont find me. WHY ?

A short summary of my code:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
        7000,
        5,
        MyLocationListener
);
```

Thx for answers and sorry for my poor english

**EDIT**

Thx for answers ! the problem is that i dont want to use network provider. Wifi is exelent, and 3g have a 400 meters error jejeej.

I only want to know, why google maps, using GPS, find me in 1 second with perfect position Although I stay in a house.

Your answer is "use coarse locate". If google maps use network providers befor gps, its impossible he find me so fast. :(

Answer (score 3):

GPS is using satelites, When you are indoor it can't get the signal from the satelites hence it can't find location (can't get a fix). 
The GPS needs signals from at least 4 satelites to get a proper fix, that usually takes a few seconds, once you already have a fix you can maintaine it very easly. therfore if you are using google maps it will get you a fix faster. 
To get a better understand on how GPS works, check this [link](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/travel/gps.htm.)
You might want to use [different location approachs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) for getting location indoor (coarse location could be the answer). I would also consider using the [fused location](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) by Google play services, it gives you a wrap up on the location providers and get you location based on what avilable at the time (meaning GPS, coarse - wifi or network).

Answer (score 2):

You should try using Coarse locates for a quick locate followed by a fine locate to have a more accurate location. The coarse locate is usually very fast, while the fine one takes more time.

Basically, the idea is to do multiple locates and overriding the less accurate ones by the newer and more accurate locates.

You can find more info on the Android dev doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

EDIT: if Google Maps is able to find you so fast, it is because you are not moving and they use the knowledge of the last location. Please read the above link that gives a lot of useful information for Location strategies (and it works very well).